# Can I change the Layout of the TFS Test Case?

Tags: testing, tfs

We use Test Cases in **Microsoft Test Manager 2010** to handle much of our acceptance testing, however we want to change the description for the Test Cases to HTML (something we have done for other work item types) and possibly make further changes...

- Is it possible to change the Test Case work item template without breaking the Test Manager?
- If changes can be made, are there any limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with some restrictions. Test Steps cannot be changed at all.

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2011/09/21/customize-your-test-case-work-item-template-to-enable-query-on-test-suites-test-plans-test-categories-and-execution-statistics.aspx) gives an good example of customizing.

Note that ne of the new features in MTM 11 is [Rich Text support](http://goo.gl/p6EjC) for Test Cases.
So just hold on :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't actually answer the question. We want to add other fields as well (we have custom work items for bugs and change requests and want to improve tests as well)